# Convert MySQL BigInt to date in C/C++

Tags: c++, mysql

Do anyone knows how to convert MySQL BigInt to date in C++.
I can easily convert a BitInt value to Date and back for storage without issue in java, which means I can use long primitive to control the bigint in my application.

Is it possible to do the same with C++?

Comment: Google [for "MySQL BigInt"](http://www.ozzu.com/programming-forum/mysql-bigint-date-t87402.html)? ???

Answer (score 0):

If this "bigint" of yours contains a `time_t` value, [MySQL++](http://tangentsoft.net/mysql++/)'s [DateTime class](http://tangentsoft.net/mysql++/doc/html/refman/classmysqlpp_1_1DateTime.html) contains conversions for that.